# Serial port on Raspberry Pi disconnects after several minutes and cannot be reconnected (IOError, pyserial)

Tags: serial-port, linux-device-driver, pyserial

I have a device with a RS-232 DB9 port connected to my Raspberry Pi over a USB-to-serial cable.
Initially, I am able to communicate with the device without issue using pyserial.

However, after some variable length of time, I can no longer receive messages from the device.

If I close the serial port and attempt to open a new one, using the same code I normally use:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    serial_path,
    9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
)
```

I get:

```
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 713, in _update_dtr_state
  fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I have no way to get around this error and re-establish communication with the device unless I physically unplug and replug the USB port.

In case it's relevant, the RS-232 device is connected to my RaspBerry Pi via an intermediate USB Hub and a USB extension cable.

I also tried setting `rtscts=True` and `dsrdtr=True` when creating the pyserial object. The IOError no longer occurs; however the serial device remains uncommunicative.

What might be the underlying issue here? Any guidance would be appreciated. Is there any way to detect the issue and reset the serial port via the shell, without requiring physical intervention?

Comment: *"I also tried setting `rtscts=True` and `dsrdtr=True` ..."* -- Is flow-control & modem-control actually required (i.e. specified by the mystery device), or are you just guessing?  Is the *"USB extension cable"* active or passive?  How long?

Comment: Have you checked `dmesg`? It might be that the kernel is crashed.

Comment: @sawdust I'm not sure 100% sure if flow-control/modem-control is required for the device (it's not mentioned in the COM settings provided with the device), but it works without flow-control. I only set those bits because it was mentioned in the error message and I was curious what would happen.

The USB extension cable is most likely passive (active is not mentioned in the specs); I got it from Best Buy. It is 6 feet.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for the suggestion about `dmesg`. I will try that the next time I encounter the error.